# webkit - css transition effect on a div

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, css-transitions

I am trying to do fadein/out effect when I change innerHTML of a div. Even tried example given at [safari doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/internetweb/conceptual/safarivisualeffectsprogguide/Transitions/Transitions.html)

I want the div to fade-out, change the contents and then fade-in again with new content.

```
<style>
.cv { background-color: #eee; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}
.cf {opacity: 0;}
</style>
<body> 
 <div id="main"> 
  <div id="c"> OLD </div>
 </div> 
</body>
<script> 
var c = document.getElementById("c");
c.setAttribute("class", "cf");
c.innerHTML = '';
c.appendChild(fragment);
c.setAttribute("class", "cv");
</script>
```

Please help me here

Comment: Do you have `fragment` defined somewhere else? Because if not then nothing is appended to `c`, possibly generating a JavaScript error and halting code execution.

Comment: you want it to fade-out, change the contents and then fade in again?

Comment: Yes, I want the div to fade-out, change the contents and then fade-in again with new content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I finally ended doing. Thank you all for the answers

```
init: function(fragment) {
        var c = document.getElementById("c");
        c.addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', IDR.callHook(c, fragment), false);
        c.setAttribute("class", "cv hide"); 
     },

     callHook: function(c, fragment) {
        var fp = function() {
           c.removeEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', fp, false);
           c.innerHTML = '';
           c.setAttribute("class", "cv");
           c.appendChild(fragment);
        };
        return fp;
     },
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
.cv { opacity:1; background-color: #eee; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}
.cv.hide {opacity: 0;}
</style>

[...]

<script>
c.setAttribute("class", "cv hide");
[...]
c.setAttribute("class", "cv");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I re-wrote your code -- see http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/ec64b/

I've also included some class manipulation functions for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.cv { background-color: #eee; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}
/* .cf {opacity: 0;} */
</style>
<body> 
 <div id="main"> 
  <div id="c"> OLD </div>
 </div> 
<script> 
var c = document.getElementById("c");
c.setAttribute("class", "cf");
// c.innerHTML = '';
// c.appendChild(fragment);
c.setAttribute("class", "cv");
</script>
</body>
```

Try out this code. Put script before body closing tag, not after.